# dyld: unknown required load command 0x80000022 error with Git installation

Tags: git

I am running *Mac OS X 10.5.8* and downloaded the *git-1.8.2.3-intel-snow-leopard.dmg* of Git. I ran the installation pkg on the disk, it finished installation but now everytime I type `git` in the terminal it throws the error:

```
dyld: unknown required load command 0x80000022
Trace/BPT Trap
```

Comment: is it just `git` that you enter or something like `git init` etc.

Comment: You're running 10.5 (Leopard) and you downloaded the package for 10.6 (Snow Leopard)...  sounds like the package was linked against newer libraries that you don't have (hence the error from `dyld`).

Comment: +1 @EdwardThomson - I got got here building toolchains exactly the same way - they worked on my machine (running Snow Leopard), but not on other (older ones) when I deployed it.  It's not just libraries, though.  Apple actually added dynamic linker commands that don't exist on 10.5.  If whoever built that git didn't have MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET set to 10.5 when they built, it will have used the new commands.  Presumably, since the package has "snow leopard" in its name, they didn't do such a thing.

Comment: @CarlNorum indeed!  `-mmacosx-version-min=10.5` is a fine compiler flag.

Comment: @hus787 git with or without args gives the same result.  git never gets to run, so args are irrelevant.

Comment: @gbarry meaning you are facing the same issue?

Comment: @hus787 Yes and if I recall correctly, I have gotten the same thing with a few other programs.  Even Adobe's updates fail because the OS is "too old". I suppose we could get the source for git and try to build it.